# PHP : Save a cookie from last request and use it in a GET request

Tags: php

I am trying to convert this JavaScript code to PHP because I need for another script :

```
function Auth(reefssid, callback)
{
request({
    url: 'https://api.gigaset-elements.de/api/v1/auth/openid/begin?op=gigaset',
    json: true,
    headers: {
        'Cookie': reefssid
    }
  }
  )
}
```

So, I have the reefssid as a php variable named $reefssid, but I do not know how to send it through a GET request.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you.

Comment: But I need to make the whole code in PHP

Comment: You need `file_get_contents()` or `CURL`.

Comment: This is what I tried, but I don't know how to make a GET request with CURL using the cookie

Comment: Do you have to pass it as a Cookie header or can you pass it as a simple $_GET param? This may help you with the CURL problem if you need to send it as a cookie - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872082/how-can-i-send-cookies-using-php-curl-in-addition-to-curlopt-cookiefile

Comment: I don't know, the only base I have is this Javascript code.. :/