# How to convert curl "-b" tag into php curl?

Tags: php, curl

I try to convert this curl command (proxmox api) into php curl : `curl -k -b "PVEAuthCookie=PVE:root@pam:4EEC61E2::rsKoApxDTLYPn6H3NNT6iP2mv..." https://10.0.0.1:8006/api2/json/`

I used the site https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ to convert it but it doesn't support the "-b" tag.

After some search, I tried this code :

```
<?php

$apiurlvmName = "https://10.0.0.1:8006/api2/json/";
$proxmoxid = "username=root@pam&password=mypass";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurlvmName);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $proxmoxid);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PVEAuthCookie=PVE:root@pam:4EEC61E2::rsKoApxDTLYPn6H3NNT6iP2mv...");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
    echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

But it doesn't works. The page takes few seconds to load then I get a blank page without error displayed. As if `"curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PVEAuthCookie=PVE:root@pam:4EEC61E2::rsKoApxDTLYPn6H3NNT6iP2mv...");"` were not enough.

Did I missed something ? How can I convert the curl "-b" tag correctly into php ? Thank you.

Comment: This question should be marked as dublicate, solution already exists please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872082/how-can-i-send-cookies-using-php-curl-in-addition-to-curlopt-cookiefile

Comment: You can use https://curlconverter.com/php/ which supports `-b`.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been answered hundreds of times. But just in case, let's copy it here again for those who can't find it.

-b means "COOKIE".

```
# sending manually set cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: PVEAuthCookie=PVE:root@pam:4EEC61E2::rsKoApxDTLYPn6H3NNT6iP2mv..."));

# sending cookies from file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
```